# Orchard CMS - How to use themed and httppost attributes together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, themes, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm working with Orchard 1.7.2 and in my custom module I have a number of controller actions decorated with the [Themed] attribute.

My problem is that when I also decorate any of them with the [HttpPost] attribute the theme stops working when that action is used.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you're telling the action that it shouldn't run for get requests, just for post request. An action marked as post is used for ajax request or for sending a form to the server. (As you point is legitimate to do a post request for a page, I deleted that part, but again is not recommendable)

Try to inject a IWorkContextAccessor, RequestContext and a IThemeManager to your constructor, then in your action do something like this:

```
  contextAccessor.GetContext().CurrentTheme = themeManager.GetRequestTheme(requestContext);
```

I don't know if that works, but at least you have a start point.

Comment: No... a POST request can legitimately return a response and that response can be a HTML document.  Think about when you submit a form... the "action" URL of the form is perfectly capable of returning a page for you to see.  My question is how to get that returned page to be themed?

Comment: You're right but as fas as I know Orchard follows the PRG pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Every ASP.NET MVC application should follow this pattern. I will edit my answer to put some code that could work.